# Trying to convert JSON url using the fromJSON() function, but it is not working (never finishes running)

Tags: r, jsonlite

My code:

```
library(jsonlite)
URL = "https://stats.nba.com/stats/playbyplayv2?EndPeriod=10&EndRange=55800&GameID=0021500431&RangeType=2&StartPeriod=1&StartRange=0"
the.data.file <- fromJSON(URL)
```

Simple, right? However, the code never stops running. No error message pops up, it just goes on forever. I thought maybe it just takes some time, but it's been going on for a *long* time. Maybe that's normal, and let me know if it is, but I don't think that's the case.

Comment: The problem isn't with `fromJSON`, it's that the site is declining connections that aren't from a browser session. I'm not sure what info the server is using to figure that out, but adding a user agent and calling `httr::GET` doesn't work either.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I figured that out after some more thorough Google searching and I just went with the downloading method that I found and put in the self-answer (which I'm not sure if I'm supposed to do, but whatever).

Answer (score 1):

Self-Answer (not sure if I'm supposed to do this?):

I did more testing with the fromJSON() function and found out that it works fine with other URLs. So I wondered if the problem was with stats.nba.com and looked up this problem specific to stats.nba.com, and sure enough I found other people asking the same thing. The solution that worked for me is downloading the file similar to this:

```
library(jsonlite)

curl_download("http://stats.nba.com/stats/teamgamelog?LeagueID=00&Season=2016-17&SeasonType=Regular+Season&teamid=1610612761", "nba.json")
jsonlist<-fromJSON( "nba.json")
df<-as.data.frame(jsonlist$resultSets$rowSet)
names(df)<-jsonlist$resultSets$headers[[1]]
parameters<-jsonlist$parameters
```

I don't want to take credit for this because I found it from another user's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43690743/11090853). I'm just putting it here in case somebody in the future finds it.